# Building a standalone SPA (as an HTML file) with Vue that does not require a backend

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm wanting a bit of direction regarding a project that I want to start working on.
This application is essentially just a frontend that will be sent to clients to allow them to input their data (clients, products, services etc) and at the end will spit out a Excel file that they will send back to me.
I can do all of this in the Vue frontend, I don't want the hassle of hosting this and writing a backend + API, plus the security concerns that go along with it.

What I planned to do initially is try to convert the SPA to a single HTML page. I created a mini version of the SPA and saved it using the built in Chrome 'Save As' MHTML and Complete HTML, this didn't work as my Vue-router buttons were greyed out, so I couldn't navigate through the sample pages I made.

I then found this: https://github.com/webdiscus/html-bundler-webpack-plugin
Which works with Vue (I cloned their Vue demo) but when I modified it for my project the html file would just be blank when viewed.

I could still look into the above webpack plugin further, but I'm just curious if anyone has any better ideas, or if there's a way to do this in Vue natively? I could use Electron and just make an app (have done so before) but it would be nice to create it as a raw HTML file so it could be filled out on phones/tablets etc.

Thanks

Comment: The question isn't specific for SO. You can naturally have problems with some features that require a web server like a router with unsuitable strategy (you need in-memory or hash), but here's the problem is MHTML, it's static by design and won't contain scripts. You need some tool that will bundle it to HTML (not MHTML) and embed scripts and styles as inline tags and images and other assets as data uri, you can use these keywords to search for it but I'm not aware of such tool. This doesn't look like a viable approach overall. Electron would be. If you need crossplatform, try Tauri or CDN+PWA

Comment: Hi Matt, the HTML Bundler plugin can generate static HTML pages with embedded (inlined) CSS, JS and images so you will have only one HTML file included all asets. If you need a help to configure webpack, create please an issue here: https://github.com/webdiscus/html-bundler-webpack-plugin/issues.